# wix : Is it possible to create directory/folder by specifiying relative path

Tags: wix

I need to specify path to create some database files(.mdf and .ldf) into it for my wix installer. Different computer probably have different version of sql server , so the path might be different from (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA) if my computer is using sql express. How can i get this path with wix? Is there any environment path or something similar like ProgramFilesFolder property which is equal to the full path of the Program Files based on individual computer settings.

Comment: I dont think it is possible and also it is not a good practice as it might happen there is not enough space on that drive. So i would recommend to provide option to user to provide the path where he wants to create those files.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the registry, the path to the data path is stored in:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\Setup

Note that if you're on a 64 bit system it would be:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\Setup

Note again that the MSSQL.1 portion of it is dependent on instance names.  You can do a lookup from instance name to that variable by searching the registry here:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL

I believe this will have more info: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143547(SQL.90).aspx

I assume that the default instance may be slightly different, but the machine I have has a named instance.  It may be possible to get these values via a SQL query or through Sql Management Objects as well.  I'm not sure what the best way to go about it is.

Once you get one of those values, you can put it in a property and manipulate the destination directory from there.